# Formula help needed

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to write a report that is looking for someone that HAS NOT had a certain immunization.  The problem is what ever I try for a formula it is saying they have had it or have not had the immunization.  When I go to validate it is not always correct

```
if ({table.column} in (ID#) to (ID#)) then
"Has had Immunization"
else if ({table.column} <> (ID#) to (ID#))
then "Has not had Immunization"
```

ID# was the same number for all.

Answer (score 0):

Record-selection formula:

```
// list desired immunization values; remove quotes if IDs are numeric
{table.field} IN [
  'ID0',
  'ID1',
  ...
  'IDn'
]
```

Comment: Unfortuntly that was not the answer.  I am still finding those that had had the immunization and the report is stating has not had.